# Two adjacent vertices in a polytope uniquely minimize some linear form

Tags: linear-programming

In linear programming, if we model the solution as a polytope, every vertex is a solution.

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> If $x$ and $y$ are two solutions with $n-1$ joint constraints, there exists a solution vector $c$ such that, for each $v\in P$ (the polytope of the problem) that is different from $x$ and from $y$, we have $\langle c,x\rangle = \langle c,y\rangle < \langle c,z\rangle$.

Basically, this means that only $x$ and $y$ are the optimal solutions for the problem.  But why is it true? And what is the vector $c$ that exists here?

Comment: I can't quite figure out your question, but in any case I suggest asking your TA or professor.

Comment: Hint: try getting an intuition from the 2D case. Generalizing to more dimensions is not too difficult once you understand the 2D solution to your problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus When you see text that doesn't make sense but includes one of `<` and `>`, it's a good tip is to take a look at the source. Often, it means the asker has included mathematics outside `$...$` and the parser has treated random chunks of it as HTML tags and discarded them.

Comment: Try generalizing the proof that for any solution $x$ there exists a solution vector $c$ such that $\langle c,x \rangle < \langle c,z \rangle$ for all $z \neq x$ in the polytope.

Comment: thanks guys , great intuition . i'm taking this to account . i'll